# Modify enviroment variable with putenv in C

Tags: c, linux, shell, variables

I am making my own shell in C and I have been asked to modify the enviroment variable with the function putenv(char*) and i have implemented this code:

```
char *string = NULL;
    if ((string = (char *)malloc(strlen(tokens[2])+strlen(tokens[3])+2)) == NULL){
        perror("Error malloc");
        return 0;
    }
    strcpy(string, tokens[2]);
    strcat(string, "=");
    strcat(string, tokens[3]);
    putenv(string);
```

tokens[2] and tokens[3] are the name of the variable and the new value I want to give it, respectively.
My problem is that this works only if i ask the enviroment to be listed from the extern char **environ, however, when I list it from the third argument of main (char *envp[]) the cange doesnt seem to be working.

Does anyone know how can I tell the putenv() function to change it in both?

The 2 ways of listing enviroment I use are:

```
void ShowEnviroment (char **enviroment, char * name_enviroment) 
{
    int i=0;
    while (enviroment[i]!=NULL) {
        printf ("%p->%s[%d]=(%p) %s\n", &enviroment[i],
                name_enviroment, i, enviroment[i], enviroment[i]);
        i++;
    }
}
```

The paramether `enviroment` can be `environ` (defined as `extern char **environ`) (it works fine) or `&envp` (third argument of main) (is the one that doesnt seem to show the change)

Comment: The `envp` argument for `main` is the input environment from the parent process *only*. And you really should not use `envp` *or* `environ`. The POSIX standard itself recommend to use only `getenv` to access the process environment.

Comment: `string = malloc(); strcpy(string...` is invalid.  After the malloc, `string` is not a null-terminated string, so `strcpy` can't be used.  You need `string[0] = '\0'` before the `strcpy` (or just use `sprintf`)

Comment: @WilliamPursell No `strcpy` is alright, as `string` is the *destination* (and its contents overwritten). Perhaps you're thinking of `strcat` where the destination must be a proper null-terminated string?

Comment: ... which `string` is after the `strcpy()`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes, I was thinking `strcat`.  Too much screen, too little coffee....I would defitetly prefer `sprintf` here, though.

Comment: [The Glibc documentation indicates that `envp` has the same value as `environ`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Program-Arguments.html).  Of course, that has to be interpreted as the *initial* values of these.  It is plausible that if additional environment variables are added, then different, larger space might need to be allocated.  In that case, one would expect `environ` to be updated, but `envp` is local to `main`, so cannot be updated (automatically).

Comment: rascadux, For better practice when _code is not working_, check the return values of `int putenv(char *string);` and others to make certain that your code is not already returning some error indication.

Comment: @WilliamPursell It happens to everyone... :) But +1 on the `sprintf`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program is working fine, and as intended. `envp` is a copy of `environ` at program start, and may be, unlike `environ`, never updated afterwards.

To run commands, shells (such as the one you are writing) use a combination of `fork()` + `execv()` -- and the [manual on `execv`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exec.html) notes that

> For those forms not containing an envp pointer (execl(), execv(), execlp(), and execvp()), the environment for the new process image shall be taken from the external variable environ in the calling process.

... making no reference at all to relying on *the `envp` that you received*, as opposed to *one that you may manufacture* to pass whichever environment variables you choose to your child processes when using `exec*` variants that *do* take modified environment variables as arguments.

As a side-note, using [`setenv()`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Environment-Access.html) has two advantages over `putenv`, and I would therefore recommend it:

- whatever you pass to `putenv` must persist in time; whatever you pass to `setenv` gets copied, so you need not manage its memory.
- Therefore, `setenv(char *key, char *value, int replace)` means less responsibility for you (and no need to malloc, strcat, and so on).

Both will modify `environ` for you. Note that you should not write `environ` directly (but reading it is fine, and needed because there is no `lsenv` function to *list* available environment variables); note [this warning](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exec.html):

> Any application that directly modifies the pointers to which the environ variable points has undefined behavior

Comment: "Do not use `putenv()`, and use `setenv()` instead" is a bit strong.  So is "you should not access `environ` directly".  There is no particular reason not to use `putenv()` if you are content to accommodate its particular characteristics. And provided that you are assuming Unix, you may safely *read* the environment via `environ`; you just must not *modify* it via `environ`.

Comment: Fixed the wording to respectfully prefer `sentenv` over `putenv`, and noted that *reading* `environ` is not only fine but also required for many use-cases; while writing it is still UB